# Use RFID to identify people passing through a doorway

Tags: rfid

Not sure is this is the right place to ask this - I'm not to the programming part of my project yet.

What I'd like to do is sense an RFID tag as it passes through a doorway.  I know there are different frequencies and that relates to sensing distance.SparkFun has this module at 13.56MHz but it looks like it only can read to about 10cm.  Not enough. (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10126) with an appropriate antenna be able to do it?

I'll be using a microcontroller to interpret the data.

Any resources would be helpful, and if this isn't the right place to ask, suggestions for where that is would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I've seen UHF antennas that do a much better job, can scan hundreds of tags at a time (think: laundry bin full of 500 towels, each with a tag), and have a range of 10 feet....

Comment: Hey Steve, I would be so glad to help you. Are you still looking for rfid answers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the long range RFID Tags here ? http://iautomate.com/categories/rfid/

They are 433 MHz Active RFID Tags

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with rfid quite long. You need to set up an rfid ecosystem, which antenna are you using? NearField or FarField?. There are a lot of physical variables: antennas, tag inlay, power, polarization, phase angle, etc.

You say tags will pass through a doorway, then, a Portal maybe is the solution for you. If you place the antennas at the right place on the portal, you can read better with less power. For example, 2 antennas at 18dBm is better than a single antenna at 32dBm.

For reader, I'd suggest Impinj.
For antennas, I'd suggest Mobile Mark.

Avoid Intermec! Srly!

Keep researching.
Good luck!